# Prolog Correct Dominoes Selection

Tags: prolog, clpfd

`d(2,6)` is a domino.

I have been given the problem of checking to see if a list of dominoes can be 
successfully joined together by rearranging elements in the list and also by 
swapping single dominoes.
For example, the following selection works

```
?- playout([d(3,6),d(0,4),d(3,4),d(1,3),d(1,6),d(0,1),d(4,4)]).

true.
```

because they can be arranged

```
[d(1,0),d(0,4),d(4,4),d(4,3),d(3,6),d(6,1),d(1,3)]
```

but the selection below does not work

```
?- playout([d(0,3),d(1,2),d(5,6),d(5,5),d(0,2),d(0,5),d(3,5)]).

false.
```

Comment: Please show what you've tried to solve this problem and ask a more specific question.

Answer (score 2):

This is a very interesting combinatorial task over **integers**, very well suited for Prolog's **CLP(FD) constraints**.

Here is a solution that works with at most small modifications under SICStus Prolog, SWI and YAP:

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).

dominos_arrangement(Ds, Solution, Vs) :-
        same_length(Ds, As),
        dominos_tuples(Ds, Ts),
        phrase(dominos_ids(As, IDs), Vs),
        tuples_in(As, Ts),
        As = [First|Rest],
        foldl(linked_domino, Rest, First, _),
        all_distinct(IDs),
        maplist(domino_triple, Solution, As).

linked_domino([Val,Next,_], Prev, [_,Next,_]) :-
        Prev = [_,Val,_].

dominos_ids([], []) --> [].
dominos_ids([[X,Y,ID]|Ds], [ID|IDs]) -->
        [X,Y,ID],
        dominos_ids(Ds, IDs).

dominos_tuples(Ds, Ts) :-
        phrase(dominos_tuples_(Ds, 0), Ts).

dominos_tuples_([], _) --> [].
dominos_tuples_([d(X,Y)|Ds], ID0) -->
        [[X,Y,ID0],[Y,X,ID0]],
        { ID #= ID0 + 1 },
        dominos_tuples_(Ds, ID).

domino_triple(d(X,Y), [X,Y,_]).
```

Using your example, we can already use the **most general query** to see whether the *core relation* terminates, as intended:

```
?- Ds = [d(3,6),d(0,4),d(3,4),d(1,3),d(1,6),d(0,1),d(4,4)],
   dominos_arrangement(Ds, As, Vs).
Ds = [d(3, 6), d(0, 4), d(3, 4), d(1, 3), d(1, 6), d(0, 1), d(4, 4)],
As = [d(_3398, _3400), d(_3400, _3412), d(_3412, _3424), d(_3424, _3436), d(_3436, _3448), d(_3448, _3460), d(_3460, _3472)],
Vs = [_3398, _3400, _3500, _3400, _3412, _3518, _3412, _3424, _3536|...],
_3398 in 0..1\/3..4\/6,
etc.
```

Yes, this looks very good. Note how the chain is *linked together* by variable aliasing.

In order to produce concrete solutions, we use **labeling** on the list of *variables*:

```
?- Ds = [d(3,6),d(0,4),d(3,4),d(1,3),d(1,6),d(0,1),d(4,4)],
   dominos_arrangement(Ds, As, Vs),
   label(Vs).
Ds = [d(3, 6), d(0, 4), d(3, 4), d(1, 3), d(1, 6), d(0, 1), d(4, 4)],
As = [d(1, 0), d(0, 4), d(4, 4), d(4, 3), d(3, 1), d(1, 6), d(6, 3)],
Vs = [1, 0, 5, 0, 4, 1, 4, 4, 6|...] ;
Ds = [d(3, 6), d(0, 4), d(3, 4), d(1, 3), d(1, 6), d(0, 1), d(4, 4)],
As = [d(1, 0), d(0, 4), d(4, 4), d(4, 3), d(3, 6), d(6, 1), d(1, 3)],
Vs = [1, 0, 5, 0, 4, 1, 4, 4, 6|...] ;
Ds = [d(3, 6), d(0, 4), d(3, 4), d(1, 3), d(1, 6), d(0, 1), d(4, 4)],
As = [d(1, 3), d(3, 4), d(4, 4), d(4, 0), d(0, 1), d(1, 6), d(6, 3)],
Vs = [1, 3, 3, 3, 4, 2, 4, 4, 6|...] ;
Ds = [d(3, 6), d(0, 4), d(3, 4), d(1, 3), d(1, 6), d(0, 1), d(4, 4)],
As = [d(1, 3), d(3, 6), d(6, 1), d(1, 0), d(0, 4), d(4, 4), d(4, 3)],
Vs = [1, 3, 3, 3, 6, 0, 6, 1, 4|...] ;
Ds = [d(3, 6), d(0, 4), d(3, 4), d(1, 3), d(1, 6), d(0, 1), d(4, 4)],
As = [d(1, 6), d(6, 3), d(3, 1), d(1, 0), d(0, 4), d(4, 4), d(4, 3)],
Vs = [1, 6, 4, 6, 3, 0, 3, 1, 3|...] ;
etc.
```

On backtracking, all solutions are generated.

Note the usual advantages of constraint solving in such cases, such as a significant **pruning** of the search space that makes it unnecessary to exhaustively try all combinations, and the potential to try more intelligent search strategies via labeling options.

Comment: Thank you, the task requires only to determine whether a selection of dominoes can be laid.

Comment: You are welcome. In this case, you can simply stop after the first answer.

Comment: So, how I need to change your code, that it would return just true or false?

Comment: You simply wrap the whole query into a **double negation**. Instead of `?- Query.`, you simply write: `?- \+ \+ ( Query ).`. The `\+ \+` leads to the removal of all bindings, and simply reports `true` or `false`.  In the case of the query I showed, you can write: `?- \+ \+ (Ds = [d(3,6),d(0,4),d(3,4),d(1,3),d(1,6),d(0,1),d(4,4)],  dominos_arrangement(Ds, As, Vs), label(Vs) ).`, yielding: `true`.

Comment: Actually, I have a solution so simple in plain Prolog. I don't show it because it's probably the topic of the assignment (linear recursion, select/3, elementary pattern matching). That apart, I cannot get the purpose of ID computing in dominos_tuples_. What's about it ? Just to identify the piece during computation ?

Comment: The key is in the interplay between `tuples_in/2` and `all_distinct/1`: By reusing the same ID for pieces that are only swapped, I can enfore that each original piece occurs only once in the solution! This is a good technique to restrict multisets in such a way that at most a single member of the multiset is used in the solution, by assigning the same ID to members that are in the same equivalence class, linking them to  solutions via `tuples_in/2`, and enforcing the IDs in the solution to be distinct.